# Is there a way in testNG to skip tests based on data provider input?

Tags: testng-dataprovider

For Eg:
Below is my test method and data provider. my testmethod should be skipped if data provider input is "Two".

```
@Test(dataprovider = "getData")
public void test(String data) {
    System.out.println(data + " Executed successfully");
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData(){
    return new Object[][]{
        {"One"},
        {"Two"},
        {"Three"},
        {"Four"},
        {"Five"}
    };      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your test method , you can compare the parameter data and throw a skip exception when your condition is satisfied.

```
@Test(dataprovider = "getData")
public void test(String data) {
    if(data.equals("two")){
    throw new SkipException("Test skipped as data is:"+data);
    }
    System.out.println(data + " Executed successfully");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking to skip the data before Test. Like BeforeMethod. I found out the solution to add Object[] params as an argument in BeforeMethod. Thanks again